# Trigger month change event in fomantic calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fomantic-ui

I am using fomantic calendar in my project.The calendar is displayed properly.
When the month is changed i want to do some actions.Is there any month change event in the fomantic calendar.Finding it hard to make it work.
Thanks for the help in advance.

```
<div class="ui calendar" id="calendar">
</div>
```

I have initialized the calendar like this 
ngOnInit() {
$('#calendar').calendar({
      type: 'date'
    });
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj6qq.png)

I want to do some actions when i click on the arrow icons as shown in the picture

Comment: please add some relevant code to your question, it would be easier to help that way

Comment: Please check the above screenshot and code

Answer (score 1):

The Fomantic-UI calendar module has an event `onBeforeChange` which you can use to determine a year change

```js
  $('.ui.calendar').calendar({
    type: 'date',
    onBeforeChange: function(newDate){
      var oldDate = $(this).calendar('get date');
      if(!oldDate || oldDate.getFullYear() != newDate.getFullYear()) {
        console.log('Year has changed!');
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

After the initialization, if you check out the code generated by Javascript you can see that the left arrow is in a div with `class="prev"` and the right arrow, in a div with `class="next"`.

So you can do something like this

```js
$('#calendar prev, #calendar next').click(function() {
    //do something
})
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..Unfortunately it didnt work.This is what i have :                ngOnInit() { $('#calendar').calendar({ type: 'date' }); }     ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(document).ready(() => {
      $('#calendar .prev').click(() => {
        console.log('prev arrow clicked');
      });
    });
  }